# Query in SQL - 7 Boom

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, replace, qsqlquery

I need to write a query that represents the following:

I have 1 Table "Numbers" with one column only "Num" (Integer).
The table includes data from 1 to N.

I need to write a query, that replaces the word "Boom" each time the number 7 shows up
or each time we have a number which can be divided by 7.
So at the end I get the following: 1 2 3 4 5 6 Boom 8 9 10 11 12 13 Boom 15 16 Boom 18 19 20 Boom ....

Hope it's clear :)

Thank you

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE`. For example:

```
select
  case when n % 7 = 0 or concat('x', n) like '%7%' then 'Boom'
       else concat('', n)
  end
from numbers
```

Result:

```
 Result 
 ------ 
 1      
 2      
 3      
 4      
 5      
 6      
 Boom   
 8      
 9      
 10     
 11     
 12     
 13     
 Boom   
 15     
 16     
 Boom   
 18     
 19     
 20     
 Boom   
 22     
 23     
 24     
 25     
 26     
 Boom   
 Boom   
 29     
 30
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8M83t7T5VfZES9LogGDNhn/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can literally translate your requirement to SQL (taking into account the fact that "Boom" is a string and in some cases can't replace an integer).

"7 or divisible by 7" means that its remainder modulo 7 is zero.

So,

```
SELECT IF(num % 7 = 0, 'Boom', num) AS num FROM mytable
```

will do what you ask. See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60cf70/1/0)